# Unable to access a site configured on port 84

Tags: apache-2.2

We have a site configured on port 84 on Apache.  A few Windows 7 computers are unable to access this using VPN (as server resides remote). They get an error saying Server took too long to respond.  I googled a few things and found that port 84 is used for "Common Trace Facility" however; I do not think this makes a difference for client computers because they do not have IIS running or configured or any other webserver for that matter.  Please help guys!

Comment: What happens if you change the port?

Comment: well..I did not test this and does not seem to be nececssary because all people are able to access at port 84 only a few (1 or 2) are unable to access on port 84.  I do not want to change the port because site is being accessed by many users simultaneously involving contractors as well.

Comment: Perform packet captures along the network path - after doing this, you'll be able to see where things are being blocked.

Comment: Just a though, what about a windows firewall at client machine? Is the port open at client end?